# My regular expression allows spaces when formatting phone number

Tags: regex

I have the following regex being used in javascript.

```
phone_number.match(/^1-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/);
```

it works great with one exception.  It allows spaces.

I want to strictly format `1-xxx-xxx-xxxx`

but it allows `1- xxx-xxx-xxxx`

anyone have any ideas how I can NOT allow spaces?

Comment: No, it doesn't. What makes you think it matches?

Comment: As an aside, if you're using this to validate phone numbers that users have entered, what's wrong with a user entering a space? They're trivial to remove, so if the user wants to use spaces, let them.

Comment: you guys are correct, JQuery was doing something goofy.  Upgraded to newest JQuery, and worked correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. ;-)
It is just impossible. In your regexp `/^1-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/` you do not have any space character - and it does not match (checked).